# API call gets blocked once pushed to AWS pipeline

Tags: javascript, java, amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codestar

I am doing a project and hosting a website on Amazon Web Service using CodeStar and a node.js web application. I want to implement a simple public API from Nasa using javascript. In cloud9 it works fine but as soon as I push it to my master branch and the AWS pipeline has finished deploying it, my website does not want to make the API request and I get the error: "Missing authentication token"

Here is the code:

```
https.open("GET", "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=zuOehZm6hq1Rt9cufqw36ADo0kZT3mfq5dGmCPNo", false);
  
    https.onreadystatechange = () => {
      
    if(https.status == 200 && https.readyState == 4){
        var vals = JSON.parse(https.response);
        console.log(vals);
    }else{
      console.log(`error ${https.status} ${https.statusText}`);
    }
}

https.send(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try enabling CORS for the API